# Torque qsub : Change the ouput/error file destination doesn't work

Tags: output, pbs, torque

If I did : qsub myscript.sh
Then it creates in the script path: myscript.sh.e12 and myscript.sh.o12 files.

But if I do : qsub -o /tmp/my.out myscript.sh
Then there is nothing in /tmp and in the script path only the myscript.sh.e12 file.

The output file is lost during the move. I don't know why.
I also tried with #PBS -o  in pbs file but same result.

Thanks for your help.

Torque 2.5.7
RHEL 6.2

Comment: Is there any information in the logs?

Answer (score 2):

short answer: don't write output to `/tmp/`, write to some space you own, preferably with a unique path.

long answer: `/tmp/` is ambiguous. Remember: the whole point of using a [distributed resource manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_resource_manager) is to run a job over multiple, or at least multiply assignable, compute resources. But each such device will almost certainly have its own `/tmp/`, and

- you have no way of knowing to which one your job was written
- you may have no rights on the `arbitrary_device:/tmp/` on which one your job was written

So don't write output to `/tmp/`.